# Time components of propagation

Tags: networking, telecommunication, propagation

I had a homework assignment for school and it dealt with calculating the propagation time of information sent from various places around the world.

The next question asked me to find the difference from the download time from the various places and the estimated propagation time, both in milliseconds. The next part is what confused me, it asked " what time components must this include?"

I dont even know what time components are and have never heard that term in my 4 years of dealing with computers and networks.

Thanks for you help in advance!( The question is posted below)

1. Compute the difference between the measured download time and estimated propagation time and put the result in the "difference" column.  **What time components must this value include?**

Answer (score 0):

I understand the question to mean "how do you explain the difference between the measured download time and the estimated propagation time?"
So, for example, if you decided that the difference was due to packets having to be re-sent, due to a poor connection, then the "time components" would be time delays due to re-sending the packets.